# What are the barriers to Voxel Cone Tracing on mobile?

Tags: opengl-es, raytracing, voxel

After watching the Unreal Engine 4 demo, I'd love to be able to use that tech in an iPad app.  I know that it's not feasible right now, as they're targeting PCs and next gen consoles, but I was wondering what has to happen in order for it to be practical on a mobile device.

Can someone knowledgable out there comment on what needs to be added to OpenGL ES to allow it to work?  I assume that there also must be much more memory available to store the voxel structures, how much do you need?  Is there anything else that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need is 3D textures - I think Opengl ES recently added an extension for this.
Geometry shaders? I don't think it has that yet - but im sure there's a way (using traditional methods) to voxelize using the fragment shader.
I use a compute shader to create and filter my mipmaps of the 3d texture.
I'm sure the ability to have bindless textures will improve performance.